# Open a web page and let it refresh automatically in python

Tags: python

When you do a request in python, you simply download the page and your connection is over.

However, if you open it in your browser, for some websites the page content will automatically refresh. For example the stock prices on yahoo finance, or notifications on reddit.

Is it possible to replicate this behaviour in python: automatic refresh without having to constantly manually re-download the same page entirely?

Answer (score 1):

These websites use this thing called websockets, which allows you to easily send live data back and forth from client to server. They keep a normal request open so that the server can send data back whenever it needs. If you need websockets, there are some resources listed below:

[MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

[100 seconds of code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BfCnjr_Vjg)

Comment: There is no support for this feature in the `requests` module, but if you were writing a web app, this is how you would do it

Comment: Thank you, I will see what I can do.

Comment: I have personally used the websockets library to do this, although it can be somewhat confusing.

https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

For websockets, you need to make sure that the data provided to you is in the form of a websocket connection. Using your expample of stock prices, heres what interactive brokers' uses for this.

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/api/doc.html#tag/Streaming

Answer (score 0):

The results will be the same if you re-download the page. Don't make it harder than it has to be. If you are hell-bent, you'll need to use something like puppeteer, phantomjs, or selenium.

Comment: The issue is me getting blocked if I make too many requests. I believe that keeping the connection will prevent that.